# How to play a youtube video when I hover on an image in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hover

Is there any ways to play a youtube video when we hover over an image.I checked react-hover-video-player but couldnt play youtube videos.The video must be played in desired size when hovered on image.

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

1. Add an event listener (mouseover) to the image you want to trigger the video from
2. Load the URL of the video into the iframe

YouTube probably requires this to be loaded from a server, and not just opened as an `index.html` file directly in the browser window.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" id="image" alt="Placeholder image" />

<div id="youtube">
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    const hoverable = document.querySelector('#image');

    function showVideo() {
        const video = document.querySelector('#youtube iframe');
        video.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/LatorN4P9aA';
        video.style.width = '560px';
        video.style.height = '315px';
        video.allow ='accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture';
        hoverable.removeEventListener('mouseover', showVideo);
    }

    hoverable.addEventListener('mouseover', showVideo);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```